# Why does my boolean not evaluate correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, devextreme

So, as the title says, my boolean does not evaluate correctly, here is my code:

```
var unindexed_frmVersionCtrl = $("#frmVersionCtrl").serializeArray();

unindexed_frmVersionCtrl[unindexed_frmVersionCtrl.length] = { name: "versionControl", value: 0 };
console.log(unindexed_frmVersionCtrl);

let historyEntry = false;

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(unindexed_frmVersionCtrl)) {
  if (value.name == "versionControlBool") {
    historyEntry = value.value;
    console.log(historyEntry);
  }
  
  if (value.name == "versionControl") {
    console.log(historyEntry);
    if (historyEntry == true) {
      value.value = 1;
      console.log("lel");
    }
    else {
      console.log("false");
      value.value = 0;
    }
  }
}

console.log(unindexed_frmVersionCtrl);
```

here is the output:

[image: historyEntry evaluates to true even when it is false.]

historyEntry evaluates to true even when it is false. I don't know what to do. No idea.
I am just starting out with javascript and I have never been this confused. Thanks.

EDIT: typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `historyEntry = value.value;`, in this case value.value is a string, not a bool.

You can do `historyEntry = (value.value == 'true');`

**Demo**

```js
var unindexed_frmVersionCtrl = [{
  "name": 'versionControlBool',
  value: 'true'
}, {
  "name": 'versionCount',
  value: '25'
}, {
  "name": 'versionControl',
  value: 0
}]

var historyEntry = false;

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(unindexed_frmVersionCtrl)) {
  if (value.name == "versionControlBool") {
    historyEntry = (value.value == 'true');
    console.log("typeof value.value = " + typeof(value.value))
    console.log(historyEntry);
  }

  if (value.name == "versionControl") {
    console.log(historyEntry);
    if (historyEntry == true) {
      value.value = 1;
      console.log("lel");
    } else {
      console.log("false");
      value.value = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welp, didn't occur to me that was a string, now everything makes sense. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The value of `'versionControlBool'` is a string `'true'` not boolean `true`. If you try `'true' == true` you'll get `false` but if you `console.log('true')` the console will log `true` as if it's a boolean so you wouldn't notice. Here's some code to try it out.

```js
var x = true;
var y = 'true';

console.log(x, 'This is the boolean true');
console.log(y, 'This is a string "true"');

console.log(x == true, 'This should be true');
console.log(y == true, 'This will be false even though the console thinks it\'s a boolean');

console.log(y == 'true', 'Whereas this will be true, as it should');
```